# --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null in android while displaying images

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I am storing images into sqlite in byte array and displaying those images from the sqlite but the problem is i am unable to display those images as they are showing

```
         --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

the code i used for that is

```
img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(map.get(POSITION), 0, map.get(POSITION).length));
```

could anyone tell me to solve this issue?

Comment: What does your byte array look like ? Are you sure there is no formating issue when you store your blob inside your database ?

Comment: i am sure !! previously i am use to get the images but i am updating a row .Now while displaying that updated row the issue raises @Snicolas